# Command \; invalid in math mode

Tags: unicode

I get this warning when I try to compile my latex file.

This is very confusing, I thought `\;` was a proper way of adding spacing in math mode. Even more confusing is that most lines generating this warning do not even contain a `\;`.

An online search suggested that some unicode character might be to blame. But which? The lines do not seem to contain any.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the TO found the root cause, see answer.

Comment: In any case, for such questions, you should provide a MWE so that we may be able to detect what could possibly have gone wrong. Debugging without actually having any source code is about as easy as reading while blindfolded.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the answer was that the `tipa` package was doing weird thigs.

Comment: Probably `tipa` isn’t necessary in most math documents.